# Returning rows that match a list of inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server database that stores recipes and in this database there is a view that returns

```
ingredient_name, ingredient_plural_name, recipe_id, recipe_name, recipe_description, tag_name
```

(among other information not pertinent to this question).

The way the database is set up, this view will return a new row for each combination of ingredient and tag in the recipe (my test entry has 7 ingredients and 2 tags, so it returns 14 rows for this recipe) like this:

| ingredient_name | ingredient_plural_name | tag_name | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all purpose flour | NULL | dessert | The rest of the data is the same in all records |
| all purpose flour | NULL | simple |  |
| baking powder | NULL | dessert |  |
| baking powder | NULL | simple |  |
| egg | eggs | dessert |  |
| egg | eggs | simple |  |
| milk | NULL | dessert |  |
| milk | NULL | simple |  |
| unsalted butter | NULL | dessert |  |
| unsalted butter | NULL | simple |  |
| vanilla extract | NULL | dessert |  |
| vanilla extract | NULL | simple |  |
| white sugar | NULL | dessert |  |
| white sugar | NULL | simple |  |

I want to write a stored procedure that returns the `recipe_name`, `recipe_description`, and `recipe_id` only if the tags and/or name/plural name contain **all** values provided as a parameter input.

The recipe can have more tags and ingredients than the ones specified, but it must contain all of the ones specified. For example, it should return this sample recipe if I do

```sql
EXEC search_include @includeTags= 'milk, eggs'
```

but NOT if I do

```sql
EXEC search_include @includeTags= 'milk, eggs, cheese'
```

Am I missing something, or is this going to be a bit convoluted?

I currently have this code:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[search_include]
    (@includeTags varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        recipe_name, recipe_description, recipe_id
    FROM 
        recipe_view 
    WHERE 
        tag_name IN (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.split(@includeTags))
        OR ingredient_name IN (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.split(@includeTags))
        OR ingredient_plural_name IN (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.split(@includeTags))
END
```

And it works to only show results where tags and ingredients are included in the list, but I need it to only return results of recipes that match ALL of the inputs.

I have also tried this approach:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tags (tag varchar(100))

    INSERT INTO #tags 
        SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.split(@includeTags)

    SELECT recipe_id
    FROM recipe_view 
    WHERE tag_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
       OR ingredient_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
       OR ingredient_plural_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
    GROUP BY recipe_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tags)

    DROP TABLE #tags
END
```

From some similar (but not quite the same) questions from this site. This one gives me no results whatsoever, no matter what I type for the parameters.

The `dbo.split` function just takes a comma separated list as a `varchar` string and returns a pseudo table of each item in a new row in a "VALUE" column.

I'm not great with SQL by any means, and I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around getting this right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a query that: Given a distinct list of recipes, select each recipe where all tags are present in the ingredients for that recipe.

The "where all tags are present in the ingredients" is logically equivalent to "where none of the tags are missing from the ingredients". This seemingly double-negative can be achieved with nested `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` conditions.

Something like:

```
SELECT R.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT recipe_name, recipe_description, recipe_id
    FROM recipe_view R
) R
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM #tags T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM recipe_view I
        WHERE I.recipe_id = R.recipe_id
        AND (
            T.tag = I.tag_name
            OR T.tag = I.ingredient_name 
            OR T.tag = I.ingredient_plural_name
        )
    )
)
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B-qaaMar).

Using the view repeatedly in this query can be inefficient. If you hae access to the underlying tables, it may be wise to rewrite the above to access those tables directly.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I didn't think about using logical parallels like this, and looking at the code it makes perfect sense. I appreciate you mentioning that the solution is less efficient, but as this is a sample program for a class, I'm not terribly worried about that. Knowing for the future is great though! Thanks for the great response!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the view that creates multiple rows for the same ingredient. For example, if you had the two tags and just did a SELECT with the above e.g.,

```
SELECT *
FROM #recipe_view 
WHERE tag_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
    OR ingredient_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
    OR ingredient_plural_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags);
```

It will show 4 rows

```
ingredient_name ingredient_plural_name  tag_name    recipe_id
egg             eggs                    dessert     cake
egg             eggs                    simple      cake
milk            null                    dessert     cake
milk            null                    simple      cake
```

Therefore `COUNT(*)` will return 4 - and not match the HAVING clause (which is expecting a count of 2).

I suggest

- Instead of having the 'recipe_view' look like that, instead you combine all relevant ingredients/tags etc into a single column
- Do a matching similar to your answer above.

[Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hv739WIc) that starts with the recipe_view, converts it to a single column to check (`recipe_tag`) then does the check.

I expect you have a better way of doing this (given that the view is already selecting data from elsewhere) but the 'view' I use (actually a temporary table called `recipe_tags`) has the following data/structure - with all the tags/etc relevant to the recipe.

```
recipe_id   recipe_tag
cake        all purpose flour
cake        baking powder
cake        dessert
cake        egg
cake        eggs
cake        milk
cake        simple
cake        unsalted butter
cake        vanilla extract
cake        white sugar
```

Then you can do a similar approach as you have above against this table

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM #recipe_tags
   INNER JOIN #tags ON #recipe_tags.recipe_tag = #tags.tag
GROUP BY recipe_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tags);
```

This has the expected output - the recipe_id (in this case 'cake').

Comment: So what you're saying is to join the tags and ingredients columns on a new column in the return table and then the HAVING clause will work properly. This makes sense when explained this way, but since I have other systems in place that are dependent on the format of recipe_view, I'll probably stick with T N's solution. I really appreciate the answer though, I definitely learned a bit about what I was initially doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve this functionality is to *union* all of the three columns that are required to match with, then use the distinct count to check if the three columns have all of the tag values.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_include
  @includeTags varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE #tags (tag varchar(100));
  INSERT INTO #tags 
        SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@includeTags, ', ', ','), ',');

  with rv as 
  (
    SELECT recipe_id, ingredient_name as attribute_value
    FROM recipe_view WHERE ingredient_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT recipe_id, ingredient_plural_name
    FROM recipe_view WHERE ingredient_plural_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT recipe_id, tag_name
    FROM recipe_view WHERE tag_name IN (SELECT tag FROM #tags)
  )
  SELECT recipe_id
  FROM rv 
  GROUP BY recipe_id 
  HAVING COUNT(distinct attribute_value) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tags);
  
  DROP TABLE #tags;
END
```

The use of `REPLACE('milk, dessert', ', ',',')` inside the split function is to remove the space that may exist in the parameter value, i.e.'milk, eggs' -> 'milk,eggs'.

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fSXI_T6i)

Comment: This is an interesting option. My current split function already removes spaces, but the inclusion of that is much appreciated! From what I can see, this works about the same way as seanb's solution but without modifying my recipe_view, which is ideal. The difference in this solution and T N's is that you're only retrieving the recipe_id by the end and while I'm sure that's a relatively trivial fix, it was giving me fits, which is why I went with their solution. Seeing and trying this method was a great learning experience, though, and I do appreciate your response!